# How do I get an iframe-embedded HTML5 video to embed in a Facebook news-feed?

Tags: facebook, iframe, html5-video, facebook-opengraph

I know how to make a shared URL show an embedded Flash video in the Facebook news-feed. The `<og:video>` tags are straight-forward but the [examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) are only for Flash-video.

I've read that you can set `og:video:type` to `text/html` for html5 embeds, but it doesn't work for me. Facebook just opens the video-player in a new window instead of inline.

I'm using the following:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://url_to_video_player_for_iframe" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="392" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
```

What `og:video:type` do I need to get the player inline? Or is there another `meta` tag necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I did this once for a client you need to apply to facebook to let them allow you to put videos inline into wall streams. you provide them with details and they check you out then enable this for your domain (or don't) I think it's to stop adult content etc.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like they no longer have an application process, but it seems you only have options to embed an swf file, an mp4 file or link to a new window. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: good to know, thanks for this, wonder what theyre doing now to stop adult content and copyrighted stuff now?